# BeautifulSoup4 returns an empty list for no reason

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-3.4

I have some data in a txt file, I'm trying to find some specific words in this file.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open ("myfile.txt") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f)

    print (soup.find_all("DLC"))
```

There are at least 5 `DLC` in the file, but output is an empty list. I changed `soup = BeautifulSoup(f)` as `soup = BeautifulSoup(f),"html.parser"` but didn't work. Why it returns an empty list since I know that string is in the file already. Also it doesn't work on the website that I pulled this data. How can I fix this problem?

Edit after comment: For example;

```
<h1>Fallout 4'ün Far Harbor DLC fragmanı yayımlandı!</h1>
<h2>Bethesda'nın yaptığı en geniş DLC geliyor</h2>
```

Comment: Could you post a part of the HTML where the `DLC` should be found in the document? Thanks.

Comment: `find_all` finds elements, not strings.

Comment: What kind of file are you trying to parse? `DLC` is not an HTML tag name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `soup.find_all("DLC")`, `BeautifulSoup` would *look for the `DLC` tags/elements* on the page and not the text `DLC` inside the elements.

Instead, you meant to use the `text` argument (in the modern `BeautifulSoup` [the argument is called `string`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument) instead of `text`):

```
soup.find_all(text=lambda text: text and "DLC" in text)
```

Comment: It fixed my problem, I see now. But should I make a lambda every time for finding a simple string?

Comment: @GLHF for the partial match, you can also use a regular expression instead of a lambda function: `soup.find_all(text=re.compile("DLC"))`. And, if you need an exact/precise match, you can just use `soup.find_all(text="DLC")`.

Comment: re.compile() gives the same output as lambda does, I'll use that. Thanks for the answer.